# stored exponential value in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

i used `mongoose` ORM for mongodb operation. i want to store float value in filed.

here is my model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Float = require('mongoose-float').loadType(mongoose, 8);
var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');

var mymodel = new Schema({
  amount : {type : Float},
    note : {type :String,default : ''},
}); 

mymodel.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
module.exports = mongoose.model('mymodel',mymodel);
```

the problem is amount filed is storing exponential value.
for example i store `0.00000011` db stored `1.1e-7`

how can store actual value in filed with datatype float?

Comment: JFYI, it's the same number. Don't confuse value with its representation.

Comment: but its seen same as html file

Comment: this is a matter of learning how to format numbers for display in javascript/node.js. Nothing to do with how they're stored. You need javascript's equivalent of `sprintf`